# Configure firebase for sub-app within a folder

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-hosting

I have used firebase hosting to host my app in the root however I would like to serve a separate codebase for my forum under https://myapp.com/forum/

I created two targets: app for my root app in one repository and forum for my other repository. I also created two sites in Firebase.

My question is: is it even possible to have two separate repos and use firebase deploy to have one project under root and other under /forum/

firebase.json (app):

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "!/forum/**",
    "destination": "/appIndex.html"
  }
]
```

firebase.json (forum):

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/forum/**",
    "destination": "/forumIndex.html"
  }
]
```

I would like Firebase to show app in the root and forum when I point to mydomain.com/forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain your code in two different repos but once you want to deploy to firebase you'll have to build both and deploy both from the same directory.